# How to use regex in the Grafana Message Template and replace it

Tags: regex, go, grafana, go-templates, grafana-templating

When an alert occurs, I want to create a template using Prometheus metric and value.
There was no problem when the value string is 1 array string, but there is a problem when there are N.

e.g)

```
ValueString: [ var='A0' metric='a' labels={labelA=a} value=8567.233333333334 ], [ var='A1' metric='b' labels={labelA=b} value=7853.116666666667 ]
```

as-is template: `{{ reReplaceAll "(.*) (value=)([0-9]+)(.*)" "* current: $3" .ValueString }}`

How can I get the value and value of labelA from the ValueString above and use it for template?

Expect result

```
labelA: a, current: 8567
labelA: b, current: 7853
```